# Upgrading jhipster from v5.0.1 to the latest

Tags: npm, jhipster, yarnpkg, yo

I am running linux 18.04, installed java 8. I am struggling with upgrading the current version of jhipster (v5.0.1)to the latest. I have used, yo, yarn and npm but there is no success.

With npm  I get an error below, with yo i get the [subsequent] error:

```
Using JHipster version installed globally Executing jhipster:upgradeOptions: 
Welcome to the JHipster Upgrade Sub-Generator
This will upgrade your current application codebase to the latest JHipster version
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ERROR! Current directory does not contain a JHipster project.
    at Environment.error (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:157:40)
    at module.exports.error (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1981:18)
    at module.exports.assertJHipsterProject (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/upgrade/index.js:144:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:399:25)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
    at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:400:11)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Immediate.setImmediate (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:406:18)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

[subsequent]

````
? Generators to update (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)generator-jhipster
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/lelo/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ad/54/831265f841b3fd278d23c4c96b06a32656a62c88fddaa7739f419602a04d'

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lelo/.npm/_logs/2019-08-25T22_22_40_369Z-debug.log```
````

Despite any user type, I am not getting the expected output which is the upgraded version of jhipster. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You should not have to use yo, only `jhipster upgrade` in project directory. Does your project meet the upgrade requirements? It should have a git repo containing a `.yo-rc.json` file and a `.jhipster` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are in your application directory and have git installed.

Then execute *jhipster upgrade*.

You will probably have to solve some problems of the resulting merge arising during the update.

More info: https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/